# What has changed with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, visual-studio-2015

After migrating my project from VS 2013 to  VS 2015 - I am faced with a few object reference errors.

I will identify the problem alongwith an example.

I have two classes, with the same name `StatusList` - they are under different namespaces.

```
namespace TestNS.Interop.Cache.CacheItems
{
    public class StatusList
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public StatusList()
        {
            Message = "I am a cache statuslist";
        }
    }
}

namespace TestNS.Interop.Enquiry
{
    public class StatusList
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public StatusList()
        {
            Message = "I am an enquiry statuslist";
        }
    }   
}
```

The main program makes a call to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` and looks for the first `StatusList`.

```
var manyitems = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(o => o.GetTypes());
var typeServerCacheItem = manyitems.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == name);


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintMessagefromAssembly();
    }


    private static void PrintMessagefromAssembly()
    {
        const string name = "StatusList";

        var manyitems = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(o => o.GetTypes());
        var typeServerCacheItem = manyitems.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == name);

        if (typeServerCacheItem == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No item found");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(typeServerCacheItem.FullName);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

If you perform a clean and build for this project using VS2013 the type `ServerCacheItem` returned is the class under `CacheItems`.

If you perform a clean and build using VS 2015 the type `ServerCacheItem` returned is the class under `Enquiry`.

I do realize that the code should be fixed, there is a logical error in the code - a filter criteria should exist for `CacheItem`s.
However I am trying to understand what changed with the way `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` works?

[image: Breakpoint and Order VS 2015]

Watch window VS 2015

[image: Break point and Order VS 2013]

Watch window VS 2013

Comment: Are these types in the same assembly or not? If they are, your question is really what changed in `Assembly.GetTypes()` (answer: it's now using a different order, which is fine, since the order was never documented). If they're not, your question might additionally be what changed in `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` (answer: it's now using a different order, which is fine, since the order was never documented). Either way you slice it, something that MS was free to change was changed; delving into the exact change is probably a waste of time since you can't depend on the results of your inquiry.

Answer (score 1):

As filter you only specify **ShortName** of your type: *"StatusList"*, but also you should specify namespace i.e **FullName**. `FirstOrDefault()` not guarantee that you will take exactly desired type versus another one. You must not hope that you will get exactly wanted type at this case.

```
    var typeServerCacheItem = manyitems
.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == name && o.Namespace == namespace);
```

About changes at VS2015, yes, may be they happened, but they must not guarantee you order of resulting set, you should take it on your own

Answer (score 1):

You have made assumptions about the ordering of the objects returned by GetTypes, but this is not defined in the MSDN documentation. This means that there is no guarantee that the first item will always be the same. You need to order the array first (e.g., on the namespace) before getting the first item.

Comment: Jeroen, Slava and Polyfun - thank you for your replies. I have  added some pictures to the question. To put it in perspective, this code has been in production for donkeys years. And just because I think that I should you the new VS 2015 instead of VS 2013, for development and building the project - we have to make "corrections" to the code. This would be a hard sell to business users, and makes one wonder what else may have changed.

Comment: @Raj: "Lots" is the answer if you're moving to .NET 4.6 or 4.5 from earlier versions, which is your actual issue, not so much Visual Studio. Your beef is with the runtime, not the compiler. You can still develop and compile with VS 2015, if you take care to target the correct runtime (forcing this if necessary). But that's the subject of a different question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question the correct way would be to filter the assemblies for the cacheitem.